# How to add every 12 items of an array into one <tr> set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array that every 12 items belongs to one set of data (i want to print that set into one `<tr>`). For example if my array got 24 items. I want to print first 12th items in one `<tr>` and remaining in second `<tr>` and so on. Could any one tell me how this can be done.Thanks

example array :

```
var myArray = ["1","first","Mixed","http://www.somesite.com/12.jpg","chicago","http://www.somesite.com/countries/1.jpg","false","http://www.somesite.com/logos/87.jpg","http://www.somesite.com/logos/87.jpg","winter","summer","http://somesite.com/list/thumb.jpg"];
```

This is the way i construct the array:

```
$.each($xml.find('dict>string'), function (i) {
var keyName = $(this).text();
myArray.push(keyName);

}
```

example `<tr>` to be printed via javascript:

```
<tr id="1">
<td>1</td>
<td><img src="http://somesite.com/list/thumb.jpg" height="42" width="42"></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:doit('id=1&amp;name=first&amp;type=Mixed&amp;logo1=http://www.somesite.com/12.jpg&city=chicago&logo2=http://www.somesite.com/countries/1.jpg&order=false&logo3=http://www.somesite.com/logos/87.jpg&logo4=http://www.somesite.com/logos/87.jpg&season=winter&season2=summer&thumb=http://somesite.com/list/thumb.jpg','chicago')" onclick="selectLink(this);">chicago</a><br> 
<br></td></tr>
```

Comment: Erm, did you attempt to write any code to do this with, or are you expecting the Stack Overflow community to produce the entire solution?

Comment: As a general solution that you can try to implement, you could take this html as a template, use a clone of it, figure out the order of selectors to use to populate the template, read the data in the array to use with the template, and then viola, your done. Some key terms will be "selectors", ".clone", ".text", and ".attr".

Comment: is it possible to achieve this task using array slice ?

Comment: Additionally, to what is already here above clearly sad, Try to learn how to post questions and read it before you post it. `(i want to print that set into a one inside a div)` hat this means and where is your `div`?

Comment: If you question is on an easy way to do the splits, one idea is just do your for loop, and then do a modulus 12, and when that == 0; you need a new div.. eg. `for (var i = 0; i < 24; i ++) { if (i % 12 === 0) newDiv(); fillDiv(); }`

Comment: @Keith thanks for helping me. But how inside for loop i refrence the 12 items from array to put them in one <tr>?(each 12 items from array belongs to one set of data that needs to be placed together in one <tr>!

Answer (score 1):

What you really need to do is restructure your data to use an array of objects where each object contains all the key value pairs for a single table row.

Now building the html is trivial.

While we're at it, let's get rid of that inline javascript on the link and use an event handler instead:

```js
var myArray = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'first',
    type: 'Mixed',
    season: 'winter',
    season2: 'summer',
    logo1: 'http://www.somesite.com/12.jpg&city=chicago',
    logo2: 'http://www.somesite.com/countries/1.jpg',
    logo3: 'http://www.somesite.com/logos/87.jpg',
    logo4: 'http://www.somesite.com/logos/87.jpg',
    order: false,
    thumb: 'http://somesite.com/list/thumb.jpg',
    city: 'chicago'
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'last',
    type: 'someType',
    season: 'fall',
    season2: 'spring',
    logo1: 'http://www.somesite.com/12.jpg&city=chicago',
    logo2: 'http://www.somesite.com/countries/1.jpg',
    logo3: 'http://www.somesite.com/logos/87.jpg',
    logo4: 'http://www.somesite.com/logos/87.jpg',
    order: true,
    thumb: 'http://somesite.com/list/thumb.jpg',
    city: 'new york'
}, ];


$.each(myArray,function(i, object){
    var $row = $('<tr>');
    $row.append( $('<td></td>', {text:object.id}));
    $row.append( $('<td></td>').append( $('<img>', {src:object.thumb, height:42, width:42}))) ;
    $row.append( $('<td></td>').append( $('<a></a>', {href:'#', text:object.city, class:'doIt'}).data(object)));
    $('#myTable').append($row);
});


$('#myTable').on('click','.doIt',function(e){
    // use this handler to access the data on the link
    // put your logic from "doIt()" in here instead
  e.preventDefault();
    var $this=$(this);
    console.log($this.data('name'));
    console.log($this.data('type'));
    console.log($this.data('season'));
    // etc....    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me how to restructure my data to use array objects for every 12 items inside $.each($xml.find('dict>string'), function (i) { ...} ? Furthermore, i want to <tr> be printed as example shown in my first post (with clicable thumb and with all variables inside one <tr>. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily by `spliting` string. put your all data into a string, `divide` each `12` by special character like `|`, then divide inside strings from `,` and split it twice. below is a example and I used example data to understand. hope this will help to your. refere the working demo.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>


#mytable
{
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td{
 border:1px solid black;
}
</style>

<body>

<table id='mytable'>
   
</table>




<script type="text/javascript">


var the_data = "1,first,mixed,http://www.first.com,chicago,http://www.somefirst.com/contry.jpg,http://www.somitemsone.com/logos/87.jpg,http://another.jpg,winter,summer,http://someitmeone/logo/one.jpg,http://oneone.com|2,22,2222,22222,22222,222222,22222222,22222222,222222222,222222222,22222222,22222222222";

var splited = the_data.split('|');
var create;
for (var i =0;i<splited.length;i++)
{
 
 
 create = "<tr>";
 
 var myarray = splited[i].split(',');
 for(var j=0;j<myarray.length;j++)
 {
  var value = myarray[j];

  create += "<td>"+value+"</td>";
 }

   create += "</tr>";

$("#mytable").append(create);

}






</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**like above you can print your other data also. have a nice day**

Comment: Many thanks for helping me .how to add special character like | when i create my array?(for every 12 items how to add special character?)This is the way i create the array: $.each($xml.find('dict>string'), function (i) {
       
           var keyName = $(this).text();
           alert(keyName);
           the_data.push(keyName);
}; Furthermore, i want to use the 12 array variables inside <tr> as shown on first post not just as table!How to achieve that .Thanks